# ansible regex is not working with numbers

Tags: ansible

an excerpt from my ansible playbook

```
- name: replace variable
  ansible.builtin.replace:
    path: "{{ item }}"
    regexp: '(?x)(--my_variable(\s|\t)*=(\s|\t)*")(.*?)((\")(\s\\\n)|(\"(\s|\t)))'
    replace: "\\1{{ my_number }}\\5"
```

I have a variable in ansible vault `my_number` this variable has a value `222`

when the `line replace: "\\1{{ my_number }}\\5"` gets executed I get an error saying
that my capture group is wrong, however, if I replace variable with a string literal, i.e
`"my_number = ytiuytuytiu"` everything works as expected where `"my_number = 3333"` fails.

My questions

Why does it fail to replace when `my_number` is a number?

why does it succeed to replace when `my_number` is a String?

How to solve this issue?

P.S

Regex is crafted to match and replace the strings of this type

```
 --my_variable="333" \
```

The error looks like this

```
raise s.error(\"invalid group reference %d\" % index, pos)\r\nsre_constants.error: invalid group reference 18 at position 1\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When ansible is doing something weird, the solution is almost always to increase the verbosity `ansible-playbook -vv` which would have shown you the actual module arguments, and hopefully led you to the solution: by substituting in numbers with that `\1` syntax, it becomes `\1333` which no matter how the regex engine chopped it up, is an illegal backreference

The [python re.sub manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) says that `\g<1>` is the unambiguous style:

```yaml
- name: replace variable
  ansible.builtin.replace:
    path: "{{ item }}"
    regexp: '(?x)(--my_variable(\s|\t)*=(\s|\t)*")(.*?)((\")(\s\\\n)|(\"(\s|\t)))'
    replace: '\g<1>{{ my_number }}\g<5>'
```